# How to select from Table by group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

```
idjob category customer
1560   001        1
1560   0010       1
1560   002        1
1562   001        2
1562   0010       2
1563   001        2
1563   002        3
1563   0010       3
1563   004        3
```

One customer can have more idjobs.
Every single jobs contain a group of categories.

I would like to select the number of customer that have two or more specifics category by its jobs.

Probably it is a simple query.

How can i do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of different `idjob` per customer:

```
SELECT   customer, GROUP_CONCAT(idjob) AS jobs
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY customer
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT idjob) > 1
```

Comment: What is about to specify which categories?

Comment: @Ento you can use `group_concat` to list them all - see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get the customers meeting the condition using:

```
select customer
from t
group by customer
having min(category) <> max(category);
```

To get the number, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select customer
      from t
      group by customer
      having min(category) <> max(category)
     ) c;
```

Note that "2" is a special case.  It can be handled by comparing the `max()` and `min()`.  The more general solution would use `count(distinct category) >= 2`.  However, `count(distinct)` is more resource intensive than simpler aggregation functions.

EDIT:

Perhaps I misread the original question.

If you want customers with a particular set of categories, you can still use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select customer
from t
where category in (. . .)
group by customer
having count(*) = <n>;
```

Here `. . .` is the list of categories you want.  `<n>` is the number of categories in that list.

If you can have duplicate `customer`/`category` pairs, then use this `having`:

```
having count(distinct category) = <n>
```

Comment: It seems works. But operatore IN has a behaviour like OR. 
For example:


select customer
from t
where category in ('001', '0010')
group by customer
having count(*) => 2;



Give me the list of customer that have jobs with categories 001 OR 002.
I would like all the customer ONLY with categories specified.

I tried: 


select customer
from t
where category = '001 AND category = '0010'
group by customer
having count(*) => 2;


But it doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: @Ento . . . Run the query as specified with the `OR` condition and the `HAVING` clause.  You need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` if your original data can have duplicates (I updated the answer).